# How to call file from different user folder in same server?

Tags: php

I got 1 server with 2 users :

```
user 1 path : /home/user1/public_html/

user 2 path : /home/user2/public_html/
```

lets say i put my **function file inside user 1** folder, how am i going to **call the function from user 2**?

im thinking of using include / require_once command , but i dont have idea on how to get this done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify absolute paths when you include:

```
require_once '/home/user1/functions.php';
```

You need to make sure the web server has permission to read from the folder though, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: u mean the allow_url_include ?